# How to cut/trim line in statusline?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, statusline, error

I'm trying to cut string returned from fugitive plugin. It returns branch name of current file. By default returned string is `Git(branchname)` and this is why I want to get rid of odd `Git(..)` wrapper. So here is the code:

```
...
set statusline+=%{strpart(fugitive#statusline(), 4, 1)}
...
```

When I update `.vimrc` it returns error:

```
E540: Unclosed expression sequence: statusline+=%{strpart(fugitive#statusline(),
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Values used in `:set` are strings. See [`:h set-args`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Aset-args):

```
                                                :set-args E487 E521
:se[t] {option}={value}         or
:se[t] {option}:{value}
                        Set string or number option to {value}.
                        ...
                        White space between {option} and '=' is allowed and
                        will be ignored.  White space between '=' and {value}
                        is not allowed.
                        See option-backslash for using white space and
                        backslashes in {value}.
```

You should escape the spaces:

```
set statusline+=%{strpart(fugitive#statusline(),\ 4,\ 1)}
```

Consider the example from the help for [`fugitive#statusline`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt#L339):

```
set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%{fugitive#statusline()}%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

Note how all the spaces (all two of them, anyway) are escaped.

---

Aside:

`strpart(x, 4, 1)` is a single character, which is probably not what you wanted. [`split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Asplit) might be more useful:

```
:echo strpart(fugitive#statusline(),4,1)
(
:echo split(fugitive#statusline(), '[()]')[1]
master
```

So, you probably want:

```
set statusline+=%{remove(split(fugitive#statusline(),'[()]'),1)}
```

This will error out outside git repositories. It might better to write a small function at this point:

```
function! Current_git_branch()
    let l:branch = split(fugitive#statusline(),'[()]')
    if len(l:branch) > 1
         return remove(l:branch, 1)
    endif
    return ""
endfunction
```

And then:

```
set statusline+=%{Current_git_branch()}
```

Comment: Hm...`:echo split(fugitive#statusline(), '[()]')[1]` works perfectly, but when I place the last line you suggested `set statusline+=%{...` it returns error: `E684: list index out of range: 1`. What's wrong!?((

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov are you running it in a window whose directory is not in Git? I get that error if I'm not in a git repository.

Comment: Right! And it always append "0" if a file isn't in git repo. Can you please suggest how to prevent this error (I mean place nothing if the file isn't in git repo)?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov see update.